# Observable with autoCompleteTextView android

Tags: android

I am using an implementation of AutoCompleteTextView in which suggestions are fetched from webapi and displayed based on user input. I am using retrofit client for making network connection and  observable for response, if two requests are sent from client one after another, how observable handle responses so that only last response is handled at client.

I could not post my code now, however in case of problem i will post it.

I am more concerned with response like assume user types a character and request is sent for suggestions after a specific time interval, before response can be received at client(delay may be due to any reason at server end) user types  next character so the request will be sent for new list of suggestions. My requirement  is that the response from first request should be invalidated and only latest response should be considered.

Comment: It helps to get better and to-the-point answers if you can post the part of the code where you need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handled delay by implementing autoCompleteTextView class and overriding performFiltering by below code.

```
private val MESSAGE_TEXT_CHANGED = 100
private val DEFAULT_AUTOCOMPLETE_DELAY:Long = 3000

 override  fun performFiltering(text: CharSequence?, keyCode: Int) {
        mLoadingIndicator.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        super.performFiltering(text, keyCode)
        mHandler.removeMessages(MESSAGE_TEXT_CHANGED)
        mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_TEXT_CHANGED, 
       text), mAutoCompleteDelay)

}
```

mHandler is object which is created in implementation of autoCompleteTextView for handling request.

Answer (score 0):

A way to handle this gracefully is to use debounce. I'll assume you already know how to make an observable from the `AutoCompleteTextView`.

Let's say you have this Observable `autoCompleteTvObservable`.

```
autoCompleteTvObservable.filter((it)-> it.length() >= 2)
                .debounce(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Filter above is just filtering the TextWatcher so that it will only trigger if length of inputted text is greater than or equal to 2, then debounce will wait 1 second and then just execute the observable afterwards with the last inputted text.

With this you can make sure that only the last version of the input would get queried.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using debounce as debounce will give the latest emitted observable and it will emit after the time specified and comboning it with publish subject will give you a +

```
  PublishSubject<String> subject;
        subject = PublishSubject.create();
        subject.debounce(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .onBackpressureLatest()
                .subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(String s) {
                        // Whatever processing on user String
                    }
                });

        autoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {    }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {    }
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                subject.onNext(s.toString());
            }
        });
```